# A disk of radius 1 is cut by a line so that the center of mass of the smaller piece lies halfway along the radius.

Tags: calculus, integration

> A uniform disk with radius of 1 is cut by a line so the center of mass of the smaller piece lies halfway along the radius. How close to the center of the disk should the cut be made?

This is a *problem plus* question from Stewart Calculus Early Transcendental. Not homework problems so we didn't cover in class. I would love to know the solution, because I want to see how these application problems work to help me learn the content better.

Comment: Sorry, the center of mass of the smaller piece lies halfway on the radius..... I want to see how these application problems work to help me learn the content better.

Comment: This look s like it will be an integral but I am having difficulty understanding how it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $\quad\displaystyle\int_y^\tfrac12\sqrt{1-x^2}~dx~=~\int_\tfrac12^1\sqrt{1-x^2}~dx\quad=>\quad y\approx0.172.\quad$ It's the same as finding

the root for the transcendental equation $z+\sin z=\sqrt3-\dfrac\pi3~,~$ and then evaluating $y=\sin\dfrac z2$.

$$~$$

$~~$ [image]

Comment: I had initially set up my integral the way that you show, I am still confused on how to determine where the cut would be, and why it makes 1/2 the center of mass. I understand that would mean the area of the piece is the same amount both left and right of the 1/2 Mark?